# Get List of network SQL servers back

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to figure out how to get back the list of SQL servers in my **Visual Studios** (2012, 2015) and even in MS SQL Server management studio... I've been searching for a solution but I'm lost. Is there any way to get these servers back? Everything is working properly, I can write server manually but I'm to lazy to ask my colleagues.

The `SQL Server Browser` service is running. There are no Windows updates to install and the computer has been rebooted many times.

Thank you for any advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To me, this drop-down list is too slow. I even don't want it here.

Comment: I see. But in our network are plenty of servers with strange names...

Answer (score 0):

> The SQL Server Browser service is running

Do you mean on your computer? You'll need it running on the machines you are trying to get to appear in the list.

It's a pretty standard dialog - assuming that it uses the same technology as SSMS, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188200.aspx):

> This dialog is populated by the SQL Server Browser service on the
>   server computers. There are several reasons why the name of an
>   instance might not appear in the list:
>
> - The SQL Server Browser service might not be running on the computer running SQL Server.
> - UDP port 1434 might be blocked by a firewall.
> - The HideInstance flag might be set.

Comment: Then we come to the old question - what did you change since then? I'm nNot sure anyone can help you with that one.